# what is the use of package-lock.json?

Tags: package.json, package-lock.json

Can anyone please let me know the exact use of package-lock.json file ?

Though many have mentioned that it is used for viewing the versioned dependency tree.

Looking for simple and easier explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To avoid different library dependencies being pulled in when you amd a team mate do npm install

Comment: Recently been experiencing lots of merge conflicts in package-lock.json .. how do I avoid it ?

Answer (score 3):

`npm install` uses this file to make sure that the packages it is going to install are the same as specified in this file. It makes the `npm install` operation consistent across different machines. Thus, you will be less likely to nuke the `node_modules` folder.

In addition to a more consistent packages view, GitHub also uses `package-lock.json` [to scan](https://blog.github.com/2017-11-16-introducing-security-alerts-on-github/) if your repository contains known security vulnerability.

You can use [lock-walker](https://compulim.github.io/lock-walker) to visually walk the dependency tree in `package-lock.json` - especially useful when checking out a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [npm documention](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) is quite explanatory.
Its main purpose is to provide

> single representation of a dependency tree such that teammates, deployments, and 
>    continuous integration are guaranteed to install exactly the same dependencies.

so that for example on a different system and/or by different people, the same dependencies (and same versions) will be used.
For a better explanation see [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @gtosto. I did read the same in npm doc. I saw 'install exactly the same dependencies', doesnt package.json work the same way now ?

Comment: in the package.json you can specify wildcard for example and usually you don't _control_ the version of transitive dependencies. The package-lock.json instead is more or less like a snapshot or instance of a particular dependency resolution "run".

Comment: For a better exaplanation read [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks) abaout package locks in npm